# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach') - OpenWeather

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I am working on a weather app project in React as a beginner. I am using OpenWeatherAPI in that case.

My problem is when I try to use forEach, it gives an error as it seems below.

```
ApiCall.jsx:15 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach')
```

Here is my Header component:

```
import ApiCall from './ApiCall';

function Header() {
    const cities = ["İstanbul", "Ankara", "İzmir"]

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="header">
                <select name="selection">
                    <option value="istanbul">{cities[0]}</option>
                    <option value="ankara">{cities[1]}</option>
                    <option value="izmir">{cities[2]}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <ApiCall getCities={cities} />
        </div>   
    )

}

export default Header
```

And this is my ApiCall component:

```
import axios from "axios"
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"

function ApiCall({ getCities }) {
    const[data, setData] = useState([])
    
    useEffect(() => {
        axios(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=${selectCity}&appid=c681e6e33ec339728fdf88e0b24a2a01`)
        .then(res => setData(res.data))
        .catch(err=> console.log(err))
    })
    
    const { city, list } = data
    
    const selectCity = getCities.array.forEach((element) => {
        if (city.name === element) {
            return element
        }
    });

    return (
      null
    )
}

export default ApiCall
```

All answers will be appreciated.

Comment: What does the `getCities.array` supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

The foreach should be like this

```
getCities.forEach
```

Instead of

```
getCities.array.forEach
```

What do you think ?

If getCities is an array , you have to use forEach on it instead of using .array.forEach

Comment: It was created automatically and I thought no problem.

Comment: Yes it happens in the code editor.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you try to filter all the available cities with the cities you are getting as property to your component (`getCities`).

Since `getCities` is an array you can directly call the `forEach` function on it and loop over the cities but since you want to apply a filter I think you are better off using Javascript's build-in [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method.

```js
const selectCity = getCities.filter((possibleCityName) => {
        return city.name === possibleCityName)
    });
```

Comment: One little hint: The callback passed to `useEffect` executed on every component rendering. To prevent your component from calling the API too often, you maybe want to consider adding an empty dependency array to it -> 
`useEffect(() => {
        // fetching logic
    }, [])`

try it out yourself ([codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/useeffect-dependency-array-6hlfe4?file=/src/App.js))